# How to push items to ruby array using loop

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create an array of dates using loop. But the loop is only pushing one date and when I query an array I see it's not an array, rather a list. Help.

```
date1 = '01-01-2019'.to_date
dates = []
count = 0
repeat = 3

while (count < repeat)
 count += 1
 date2 = date1 + count.month
 dates << date2
 puts dates
end
```

Expected results should be **[01-02-2019, 01-03-2019, 01-04-2019]**.

However, if I use rails console, all I get are the dates in a list. If I ***raise dates.inspect*** in controller, I only get **01-02-2019**.

How can I fix this?

Comment: FYI: terms _list_ and _array_ in Ruby are the exact synonyms.

Comment: `dates = 3.times.map { |i| '01-01-2019'.to_date + i.months }` does what you assumingly need.

Comment: I tested your piece of code and it's working fine. [Fri, 01 Feb 2019, Fri, 01 Mar 2019, Mon, 01 Apr 2019]. Check if the moment you are formatting the result is okay.

Comment: Thank you Aleksei ant Tiw. So does that mean I can't use my other approach?

Comment: @kandy. I've tried it again. Same result. A list in console, and only one date if I raise dates.inspect in controller.

Comment: Tried in rails console, in browser and rails server log. It works fine.

Comment: @Tiw, a small thing, but I think it's clearer to change `map`'s receiver to, say, `(1..repeat)` or `1.upto(repeat)`.

Comment: Here's a hint: in Ruby, the answer to *every* question of the form "How do I *X* using loops" is "You don't, use `Enumerable` methods instead". If you *ever* find yourself writing a loop in Ruby, there's a 99.999% chance you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you raising an exception _inside_ the loop? That way you'd get the loop interrupted and only get the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your coding style it seems you're pretty new to Ruby. A more Ruby-like approach would be:

```
start_date = '01-01-2019'.to_date
repeat     = 3

dates = 1.upto(repeat).map { |count| start_date + count.months }
# or
dates = (1..repeat).map { |count| start_date + count.months }
```

Then to print the dates array use:

```
puts dates
```

As far as I can tell, your provided code should work. Keep in mind that [`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/IO.html#method-i-puts) prints arrays across multiple lines. If you want to display the contents of the array on a single line use [`p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Kernel.html#method-i-p) instead. The difference is that `puts` uses the `to_s` method while `p` uses the `inspect` method. Arrays passed to `puts` will be flattened and seen as multiple arguments instead. Every argument will get its own line.

```
puts [1, 2]
# 1
# 2
#=> nil

p [1, 2]
# [1, 2]
#=> [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `puts dates` by `puts "#{dates}"`.
It will print array as expected like  [01-02-2019, 01-03-2019, 01-04-2019].